# How to show random products in "description" of categories

Tags: html, magento

I am trying to make my landing pages for my products on my website but i want it to show up random products at the top of the page (in the description box). I have got all the code to get the random products in random.phtml and it works because i tested it on a "Test" CMS page with the code:

```
{{block type="midmedssettings/product_list" num_products="5" category_id="145" template="catalog/product/random.phtml"}}
```

However when I put this into the Description box in my category it doesn't recognise it as code and only displays the code. I did try

```
<block type="midmedssettings/product_list" num_products="5" category_id="145" template="catalog/product/random.phtml">
```

but that didnt display anything.

random.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   design_default
 * @package    Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>

<?php
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setData("product_collection",NULL);
$this->_productCollection = null;
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
?>

<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="padder">
<div class="note-msg">
    <?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php else: ?>

<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<div class="listing-type-grid  catalog-listing padder"> <!-- the class name will change to .listing-type-cell if viewing in list mode -->
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>

    <?php $_items = $_productCollection->getItems(); 
           shuffle($_items); ?>

    <table cellspacing="0" class="generic-product-grid" id="product-list-table">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_items as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%4==0): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php endif ?>
        <td>
            <p class="product-image">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170, 170); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
                </a>
            </p>
            <h5><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h5>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <!--?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?-->
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="add-to">

                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <li class="add-to-cart-textlink"><a href="#" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span>Add to Cart</span></a></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </td>
    <?php if ($i%4==0 && $i!=$_collectionSize): ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($i==4) break;  // show 4 products max ?> 

    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php for($i;$i%4!=0;$i++): ?>
          <td class="empty-product">&nbsp;</td>
    <?php endfor ?>
    <?php if ($i%4==0): ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-list-table')</script>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Could someone please tell me where i am going wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: it isnt in a file it is in the backend of magento

Comment: You can't add block in Category description. Instead you can assign a CMS static block to your category and that block will display your Random Products

Comment: does that mean i will have to create a static block for every single category ?

Comment: you can call a single static block with containing random products code wherever you want to show them

Comment: Only problem is i have 37 different categories so i would have to make 37 new static blocks. There must be an easier way. or can is there way i can set the category_id to what ever Category is showing, then i would be able to make one static block for every category.

Comment: i want to display random products at the top of each category landing page, so the customer can see a for example of the products in that category. up to now i have just been hard coding them into the "category description" but that doesnt randomise the products it just displays what i have hard coded.

Comment: I added the random.phtml file to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For random product please follows these steps:

```
   goto app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/ here you will create a Random.php file and add below code in this file.

 <?php
     class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
            {
                protected function _getProductCollection()
                {
                    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
                        $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();
                        if($categoryID)
                        {
                          $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
                          $category->load($categoryID); // this is category id
                          $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
                        } else
                        {
                          $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
                        }
                        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
                        $collection->addStoreFilter();
                        $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 3;
                        $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

                        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
                    }
                    return $this->_productCollection;
                }
            }


  now create static block insert that code or get static block on file for view product.
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="YOUR_CATEGORY_ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4" num_products="12"}}
```

Comment: on the code i add to the static block do i have to replace "your_category_id" with my cat id or just leave it how it is?

Comment: thats the problem i dont want to have to write in the ID as i want to make one block that will work on every page, where as if i have to write a category ID i will have to make a new block for every category.

Comment: So tell me which base you have get all product?

Answer (score 0):

Try from the view.

1. Edit template/catalog/category/view.phtml
2. Place your block calling code at preferred line. Black calling code looks like below:

`$this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("midmedssettings/product_list")
                 ->setTemplate("catalog/product/random.phtml")
                 ->toHtml();`

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a CMS Static Block from your admin end with identifer `random-products` and Content

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/random.phtml"}}
```

2) In your **template/catalog/category/view.phtml**, depending upon where you want to display the products, paste the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('random-products')->toHtml();?>
```

3) In your **catalog/product/random.phtml**, paste the below code,

```
<?php


 $categoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getEntityId();
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
 $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
                       ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4));
 $_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));                  
 $_productCollection->setPage(1, 5);

 ?>


 <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>


            <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h3>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can change your design for **random.phtml** as required and on every page reload, it will show **5 random** products assigned to your category.

Comment: do i need to replace all my code in random.phtml to the above or just add it ?

Comment: ok i will give it a go and let you know how i get on, thank you